# How to solve strange cuda error in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I moved to PyTorch from Keras. I'm very new to the whole moving to  CUDA thing. I've spent hours, surfing the web and haven't been able to find anything? The fix is probably something a line or two. I'd appreciate it if someone knows how to solve this issue?

Here' my code, First I define my u-net model as a class of nn.Module like the following code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, utils


class unet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(unet, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(1, 32, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv1_1 = nn.Conv3d(32, 32, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(64, 128, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv3_3 = nn.Conv3d(128, 128, 3, padding=1)
    self.convT1 = nn.ConvTranspose3d(128, 64, 3, stride=(2,2,2), padding=1, output_padding=1)
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv3d(128, 64, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv4_4 = nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, padding=1)
    self.convT2 = nn.ConvTranspose3d(64, 32, 3,stride=(2,2,2), padding=1, output_padding=1)
    self.conv5 = nn.Conv3d(64, 32, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv5_5 = nn.Conv3d(32, 32, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv6 = nn.Conv3d(32, 1 ,3, padding=1)


def forward(self, inputs):
    conv1 = F.relu(self.conv1(inputs))
    conv1 = F.relu(self.conv1_1(conv1))
    pool1 = F.max_pool3d(conv1, 2)

    conv2 = F.relu(self.conv2(pool1))
    conv2 = F.relu(self.conv2_2(conv2))
    pool2 = F.max_pool3d(conv2, 2)        
    conv3 = F.relu(self.conv3(pool2))
    conv3 = F.relu(self.conv3_3(conv3))        
    conv3 = self.convT1(conv3)

    up1 = torch.cat((conv3, conv2), dim=1)
    conv4 = F.relu(self.conv4(up1))
    conv4 = F.relu(self.conv4_4(conv4))

    conv4 = self.convT2(conv4)
    up2 = torch.cat((conv4, conv1), dim=1)
    conv5 = F.relu(self.conv5(up2))
    conv5 = F.relu(self.conv5_5(conv5))

    conv6 = F.relu(self.conv6(conv5))

    return conv6
```

Then I run my unet like the following code. note that when defining the module I set it to the cuda. I also set the input data and its labels to the cuda.

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = unet().to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
datasets = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(data_recon, data_truth)
train_loader = DataLoader(datasets, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

def training_loop(n_epochs, optimizer, model, loss_fn, train_loader):
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        loss_train = 0
        for imgs, labels in train_loader:
            imgs.to(device)
            labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(imgs)
            loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            loss_train += loss.item()


        print('{} Epoch {}, Training loss    {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now(), epoch, float(loss_train)))

training_loop(50, optimizer, model, loss_fn, train_loader)
```

But I get this error:

> ---
>
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 training_loop(50, optimizer, model, loss_fn, train_loader)
>
> in training_loop(n_epochs, optimizer,
>   model, loss_fn, train_loader)
>         5             imgs.to(device)
>         6             labels.to(device)
>   ----> 7             outputs = model(imgs)
>         8             loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
>         9
>
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py
>   in **call**(self, *input, **kwargs)
>       491             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       492         else:
>   --> 493             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       494         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
>       495             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
>
> in forward(self, inputs)
>        18 
>        19     def forward(self, inputs):
>   ---> 20         conv1 = F.relu(self.conv1(inputs))
>        21         conv1 = F.relu(self.conv1_1(conv1))
>        22         pool1 = F.max_pool3d(conv1, 2)
>
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py
>   in **call**(self, *input, **kwargs)
>       491             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       492         else:
>   --> 493             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>       494         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
>       495             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)
>
> /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in
>   forward(self, input)
>       474                             self.dilation, self.groups)
>       475         return F.conv3d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
>   --> 476                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
>       477 
>       478
>
> RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for
>   argument #2 'weight'

I've spent hours, surfing the web and haven't been able to find anything? The fix is probably something a line or two. I'd appreciate it if someone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
imgs.to(device)
labels.to(device)
```

`.to(device)` returns a new Tensor and won't change `imgs` and `labels`. So the cuda error is valid. You can simply fix it by assigning new tensor as follows:

```
imgs = imgs.to(device)
labels = labels.to(device)
```